# alias to programs in cmd? Where are they stored?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, cmd.exe

How do I add "shortcuts" (aliases) into cmd?

For example the shortcut to HypersnapDX. On one computer I can simply enter HypSnap6.exe and Hypersnap openes. From any location. On the other computer cmd does not know the path. I do not know if Hypersnap was installed properly, but Hypersnap itself works.

Where are these aliases saved?

I looked in the environment variables and did not find anything.

Windows 7 Pro, using windows onboard tools only, as I am not allowed to install new programs.

Comment: Check your `path`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)